# ASP.NET CORE 1.0, DNX packages folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

Is it possible to configure the DNX packages folder for each project or solution? Or is fix the user directory? I wanna try to have all required packages in my solution/project folder even though I have redundancies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but it's not straightforward.

- If you're using DNX, you need to set the `DNX_PACKAGES` environment variable.
- If you're using dotnet, you need to set the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable.

If you want this configuration to be per project, then you must not set those variables globally but rather at process level. So, start a new console, set the environment variable and then launch VS/dnx/dotnet from it. That way, any child process will inherit the variable, while everything outside will not be affected.

Comment: SET DNX_PACKAGES=C:\project\packages
start C:\project\*.sln